# CakePHP 3.x: all routes to the plugin

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-routing

This is not a real question, I need a confirmation to know if I understand what I'm studying (the routes of CakePHP).

I have the plugin `MyPlugin`. By default, all requests should be directed to the plugin, so I wish that the plugin name doesn't appear in the url.

For example:

```
/pages
```

should be resolved as:

```
['controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'index', 'plugin' => 'MyPlugin']
```

The same should apply to the "admin" prefix.

For example:

```
/admin/pages
```

should be resolved as:

```
['controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'index', 'plugin' => 'MyPlugin', 'prefix' => 'admin']
```

In short, you have to imagine as if the application (so except for `MyPlugin`) has no controller.

I studied [routes](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html) (particularly [this](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#prefix-routing) and [this](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#plugin-routing)) and now I would like to know if this code is correct:

```
Router::defaultRouteClass('InflectedRoute');

Router::prefix('admin', function ($routes) {
    $routes->plugin('MeCms', ['path' => '/'], function ($routes) {
        $routes->fallbacks();
    });
});

Router::scope('/', ['plugin' => 'MeCms'], function ($routes) {  
    $routes->fallbacks();
});
```

From my tests, this seems to work. But since the routes have changed a lot compared to CakePHP 2.x, I would like to have confirmation that you have understood.

Thanks.

---

EDIT

Thanks to PGBI, this code *should* be final:

```
Router::scope('/', ['plugin' => 'MeCms'], function ($routes) {
    Router::connect('/admin', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'index', 'plugin' => 'MeCms', 'prefix' => 'admin']);

    $routes->prefix('admin', function ($routes) {
        $routes->fallbacks();
    });
    $routes->fallbacks();
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes that's correct. I think you could do shorter (to be tested, but you get the idea):

```
Router::scope('/', ['plugin' => 'MeCms'], function ($routes) {  
    $routes->prefix('admin', function ($routes) {
        $routes->fallbacks();
    });
    $routes->fallbacks();
});
```

EDIT:
To add a homepage to your admin section :

```
Router::scope('/', ['plugin' => 'MeCms'], function ($routes) {  
    $routes->prefix('admin', function ($routes) {
        $routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'index']);
        $routes->fallbacks();
    });
    $routes->fallbacks();
});
```

You don't need to repeat `['plugin' => 'MeCms']` or `["prefix" => "admin"]` since it's already defined before.

Comment: Yeah @PGBI, it's work. But now: how to add an homepage for admin prefix?

I have edited my question, by entering the code that *should* be final.
What do you think about it?